# Histogram Equalization Python For Colored Image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new at Opencv thing and

I'm trying to do Histogram Equalization  manual way and somehow my output is like 
      [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5c7N.png)

First i convert the format to YCR_CB format first  and then split it into each y,cr and cb . And then i did the histogram equalization thing on layer y.

here's my code :

```
    from __future__ import division
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    img1 = cv2.imread("sup.jpg")

    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

    y,cr,cb = cv2.split(img2)

    #y = cv2.equalizeHist(y)

    x =y

    height,width = y.shape

    hist = [0]*256
    pmf = [0]*256
    cdf = [0]*256
    levelBaru = [0]*256

    cv2.imshow("y before",x)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    for i in range(0,height):  
        for j in range(0,width):
            hist[y.item(i,j)] += 1 
            #hist[y[i,j]] += 1

    for i in range(0,256):  
            #cari pmf
        pmf[i] = round(hist[i]/(height*width),4)

    print "pmf  done"

    cdf[0] = pmf[0]

    for i in range(1,256):              #cari cdf
        cdf[i] = cdf[i-1]+pmf[i]

    for i in range(1,256):              #cari levelBaru
        levelBaru[i] = int(cdf[i]*255)

    for i in range(0,height):           #baru
        for j in range(0,width):
            for k in range (0,256):
                if(y.item(i,j)==k):
                    #print i," ",levelBaru[i]
                    y.itemset((i,j),levelBaru[k])

    img2 = cv2.merge((y,cr,cb))
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR) #supaya ga error pas di stack


    #cv2.namedWindow('result', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('result',img2)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Kinda stuck finding the bug , if someone can help me that would be awesome

Comment: You should include the output in the question, not as a hyperlink

Answer (score 2):

As per the question title you want to equalize the histogram of a colored image, by splitting it in `YCrCb` domain. There is no point in writing your own algorithm for equalizing histogram, as it seems in the code snippet attached, `OpenCV` already has a method as `cv2.eqHist()` to serve your purpose.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("path/to/Lenna.png")

img_y_cr_cb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
y, cr, cb = cv2.split(img_y_cr_cb)

# Applying equalize Hist operation on Y channel.
y_eq = cv2.equalizeHist(y)

img_y_cr_cb_eq = cv2.merge((y_eq, cr, cb))
img_rgb_eq = cv2.cvtColor(img_y_cr_cb_eq, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR)
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The author specifically mentioned trying to implement the function himself, thus I'd guess he knows about the function built into OpenCV. I disagree that there is no point in implementing your own solutions of already solved problems. It's helpful from an educational perspective: gives you a deeper understanding of the process behind equalizeHist() and teaches you many important aspects of low-level image manipulation.